# How to join data from different sheets using Query in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to make a simple cash book.

[image]

As shown in the picture, from the cash-In and Cash-Out sheets i need to consolidate and display in the monitor sheet according to the selected party.

It should be sorted by date.

sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BwtcDIJv_CiZ-7Ae8qgLr4Azttnn7pBIOoxxMxdi2fk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data, to avoid closure of the question. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easier to copy/paste as well**. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query-

```
=QUERY({QUERY('Cash In'!A2:C,"select A, C,0 where B='" & B1 & "'");
QUERY('Cash Out'!A2:C,"select A, 0, C where B='" & B1 & "'")},
"where Col1 is not null order by Col1 label Col1 'Date', Col2 'Cash In', Col3 'Cash Out'")
```

See sheet <kbd>harun24hr</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This formula will solve your problem. First goto `Monitor` sheet then delete `A3,B3 and C3` cells. Then put this formula on `A3` cell.

`=QUERY(UNIQUE({query('Cash In'!A1:C, "select A, C, 'Cash In' WHERE A is not null AND B ='"&$B$1&"'", 0);query('Cash Out'!A1:C, "select A, C, 'Cash Out' WHERE A is not null AND B ='"&$B$1&"'",0)}), "SELECT Col1, SUM(Col2) WHERE Col1 is not null group by Col1 PIVOT Col3 order by Col1 Label Col1 'Date'")`

- Get `Cash In` values `query('Cash In'!A1:C, "select A, C, 'Cash In' WHERE A is not null AND B ='"&$B$1&"'", 0)` and add a virtual column with `Cash In` with selected filter on `B1` cell at `Monitor` sheet
- Get `Cash Out` values `query('Cash Out'!A1:C, "select A, C, 'Cash Out' WHERE A is not null AND B ='"&$B$1&"'",0)}` and add a virtual column with `Cash Out` with selected filter on `B1` cell at `Monitor` sheet
- Then merge two data in a single result. (Vertically merge) `UNIQUE({data_frame1, data_frame2})`
- In last step transpose `PIVOT` and sort by date column

Result:
[image]